# Why one DIV has only one child but has three child nodes?

Tags: javascript, html

I have two divs looks like:

```
<div id="responseframe">
    <div id="oldframe"> 
    </div>
</div>
```

I thought the #oldframe DIV is the only child of #responseframe. However, when I write this in javascript,

```
    var old=document.getElementById("responseframe");
    var nodesnumber=old.childNodes.length;
    console.log("-------------Here is the nodes number of reponseframe---------: "+nodesnumber);
    var nodesname=old.childNodes[i].nodeName;
    console.log("-------------Here is the nodes name of reponseframe's child---------: "+nodesname);
```

console told me #responseframe has 3 child nodes and,

1. childNode[0] is #text;
2. childNode[1] is DIV ;
3. childNode[2] is #text

Why there are 2 #text? Thank you for any idea.

Comment: The text nodes are the inter-element whitespace surrounding the `<div id="oldframe">` start tag and its corresponding end tag.

Comment: The space means the space of my code or the space of the webpage?Why this not happen to <ul> <li></li>.....</ul>?

Comment: It will happen if you put your <li> on their own lines and/or indent them.

Comment: Either minify, insert the nodes dynamically, or put the html all in one line, if you want to avoid this behaviour in production versions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Node.childNodes` property returns all direct child elementNodes of parent element including textNodes, commentNodes.

So in your case you have:

```
<div id="responseframe"><!-- this whole space area is considered by html as single space so you got your first #text Node
    --><div id="oldframe"><!-- this area is ignored because this is not direct child area of the responseframe
    --></div><!-- this whole space area is considered by html as single space so you got your second #text Node
--></div>
```

So finally we got direct children: `#text0 #DIV(oldframe) #text1`.

If you want to get only direct elementNode (without textNodes and commentNodes) you need `Node.children`.

```
var old=document.getElementById("responseframe");
    var nodesnumber=old.children.length;
    console.log("-------------Here is the nodes number of reponseframe---------: "+nodesnumber);
    var nodesname=old.children[i].nodeName;
    console.log("-------------Here is the nodes name of reponseframe's child---------: "+nodesname);
```

Answer (score 3):

Because of you added new line after `<div id="responseframe">` and after first `</div>`.

If you put this in one line will be there is one node: div.

Html:

```
<div id="responseframe"><div id="oldframe"></div></div>
```

Output:

```
-------------Here is the nodes number of reponseframe---------: 1 
-------------Here is the nodes name of reponseframe's child---------: DIV
```

Here is fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/cassln/t7kec97u/2/